# Codehelp VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

How can I modify this code to work with more than one column ? 
example:

```
Sub demo()
  Dim RaFound As Range
  Set RaFound = Rows(1).Find("cost", , , xlPart, , xlNext)
  If Not RaFound Is Nothing Then
    RaFound.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 _€"
  End If
End Sub
```

I want to format furthermore columns like "price" and "quantity" too.
How should this code to modify ?

Thank you very much who can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see below. Words can be taken from the sheet `Range("A1:C5")` or hardcoded in an array:

```
Dim RaFound As Range
Dim words() As Variant
Dim word As Variant

words = Array("cost", "price", "quantity")

For Each word In words

    Set RaFound = Rows(1).Find(word, , , xlPart, , xlNext)

    If Not RaFound Is Nothing Then
        RaFound.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 _€"
    End If

Next word
```